want to make custom toolbar work using apexcharts
I have added apexcharts in my next app. The chart is working fine. But the problem is I want to add custom toolbar like sidebar with charts. So I added the UI for it. But now I want to make the icons functional. They are actually showing in toolbar in side.

this is the code:


interface IState {
  series: Array<{
    data: Array<{
      x: Date,
      y: number[]
    }>
  }>,
  options: {
    chart: {
      type: string,
      toolbar: {
        show: boolean,
      },
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: string,
      show: boolean,
      labels: {
        show: boolean,
        style: {
          colors: string,
        },
      },
      axisBorder: {
        show: boolean,
      },
      axisTicks: {
        show: boolean,
      },
    },
    yaxis: {
      opposite: boolean,
      show: boolean,
      labels: {
        show: boolean,
        style: {
          colors: string,
        },
      },
      axisBorder: {
        show: boolean,
      },
      axisTicks: {
        show: boolean,
      },
    },
    grid: {
      show: boolean,
      borderColor: string,
      strokeDashArray: number,
      xaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: boolean,
          color: string,
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        axisBorder: {
          show: boolean,
        },
        lines: {
          show: boolean,
        },
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      candlestick: {
        colors: {
          upward: string,
          downward: string,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

const BodyChart: React.FC = () => {
  const chartRef = useRef<ReactApexChart | any>(ReactApexChart);

  const [state] = React.useState<IState>({
    series: [{
                data: [
                // my data
                ]
              }],
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'candlestick',
        toolbar: {
          show: false, // Hide the default toolbar
          
        },
        
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        show: true,
        labels: {
          show: true,
          style: {
            colors: '#969AA4',
          },
        },
        axisBorder: {
          show: false,
        },
        axisTicks: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        opposite: true,
        show: true,
        labels: {
          show: true,
          style: {
            colors: '#969AA4',
          },
        },
        axisBorder: {
          show: false,
        },
        axisTicks: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
      grid: {
        show: true,
        borderColor: '#202530',
        strokeDashArray: 0,
        xaxis: {
          lines: {
            show: true,
            color: '#FF5733',
          },
        },
        yaxis: {
          axisBorder: {
            show: false,
          },
          lines: {
            show: true,
          },
        },
      },
      plotOptions: {
        candlestick: {
          colors: {
            upward: '#009B84',
            downward: '#FF1230',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = chartRef.current.charts;
      document.getElementById('zoom-in')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // chart.zoomIn();
      });

      document.getElementById('zoom-out')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chart.zoomOut();
      });

      document.getElementById('reset')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chart.reset();
      });

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="sidebar">
        <button id="zoom-in"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearchPlus} color='#969AA4' /></button>
        <button id="zoom-out"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearchMinus} color='#969AA4' /></button>
        <button id="reset"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUndo} color='#969AA4' /></button>
        <button id="home"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} color='#969AA4' /></button>
        <button id="menu"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} color='#969AA4' /></button>
        <button id="download"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDownload} color='#969AA4' /></button>
        <button id="selection"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMousePointer} color='#969AA4' /></button>
        <button id="zoom"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} color='#969AA4' /></button>
        <button id="pan"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrows} color='#969AA4' /></button>
      </div>
      <div className="chart-wrapper">
        <div id="chart">
          <ReactApexChart ref={chartRef} options={state.options} series={state.series} type="candlestick" height={535} />
        </div>
        <div id="html-dist"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}



note: I have tried using chartRef but it did not worked

The useRef hook might be the issue here. From the docs #caveats,
When you change the ref.current property, React does not re-render your component. React is not aware of when you change it because a ref is a plain JavaScript object.

The chart should be created by defining a unique ID, and later methods can be invoked in useEffect or button events (from react-apexcharts).
Apex Charts provides zoomX(start, end) method, where start and end can be x-axis value, or timestamp.
To reset the zoom resetSeries(updateChart, resetZoom) method can be used.
For instance to zoom-in the chart by 5-minute window around current time:
  ...


  const [state] = React.useState<IState>({
    series: [{
                data: [
                // my data
                ]
              }],
    options: {
      chart: {
        id: 'myChart' // <=== THIS
        type: 'candlestick',
        toolbar: {
          show: false, // Hide the default toolbar
          
        },
        
      },
    ...



    const _getZoomInDuration = () => {
        now = new Date();
        startTimestamp = new Date(new Date(now.getTime() - minutes*60000));
        endTimestamp = new Date(new Date(now.getTime() + minutes*60000));
        return { start:startTimestamp, end:endTimestamp  }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
    duration = _getZoomInDuration();
    
    const chart = ApexCharts.getChartByID('myChart')  // <== THIS
      document.getElementById('zoom-in')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chart.zoomIn(duration.start, duration.end);
      });

      document.getElementById('zoom-out')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chart.zoomIn(<larger.start>, <larger.end>);
      });

      document.getElementById('reset')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chart.resetSeries(true, true);
      });

    }, []);


    return (
      ...
      <div className="chart-wrapper">
        <div id="chart">
          <ReactApexChart options={state.options} series={state.series} type="candlestick" height={535} />
        </div>
        <div id="html-dist"></div>
      </div>
    )


Also, callbacks can be attached to react to chart events.

Thanks, it worked but the chart constant is like this:
const chart = chartRef.current.chart;
